# Check two string data without carriage return symbol

Tags: string, matlab, serial-port

In the serial com port channel values comes from 0 to 1023, this example from Arduino: [image: Arduino]

On the MATLAB side I parse it via function:

```
while(obj1.BytesAvailable)
    Psvoltage =  deblank(fscanf(obj1)) %, '%d', 4)
    [a, b] = size(Psvoltage)
    bb = findstr(Psvoltage, '\r')
    if ~isempty(Psvoltage)
        sPs = str2num(Psvoltage) * (100 / 1023); %
        break;
    end
end
```

But sometimes from serial port I take corrupted data like this:

[image: img]

And it is cause error in my program.

This is two string data, but without carriage return symbol, because all checking such as: `~isnan()`, `~isempty()` and `findstr(Psvoltage, '\r')` this data had been passed.

The question is: how do I check these data would be to ignore them?

Comment: Welcome to SO! In what form does the data come? Decimal values as strings? I am a little bit confused what goes wrong.

Comment: don't just post images, describe in text and give examples of the kind of input you receive (both the expected and problematic). Anyway consider using try/catch as a fallback..